# Clone private git repo in Docker file using CI/CD pipeline

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile

The task which I want to complete is installing my private git repo in my Dockerfile while running job in CI/CD pipeline.

**Local Env** : I have a Dockerfile which is able to build my image consist of cloning a private repo without any issue. It doesn't ask for any ssh key, user, password etc.

**CI/CD Env** : Same Dockerfile is not able to build on CI/CD pipeline due to git clone issue. When building same docker image below exception is thrown -

```
Running command git clone -q https://private-url/project/repo.git /tmp/pip-req-build-t2xlnbs6
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://private-url/project/repo.git /tmp/pip-req-build-t2xlnbs6 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried all possible solution from web like storing ssh-key at appropriate location, various docker images etc but none of them worked. I am also sharing my Dockerfile for reference and if anyone can suggest any solution it would be great help.

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN cp id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa (I have this file in my repo)
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

#RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
#RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
#RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

COPY ingest_client.py .
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install git+https://private-url/project/repo.git
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: `Check the logs for full command output. ` - could you please provide them?

Comment: I cannot extract log as it's in CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: you can debug it by chaning `RUN pip install git+https://private-url/project/repo.git
` to something like `RUN set +e; pip install git+https://private-url/project/repo.git ; ls -lah` so you will find log file name a then change ls to cat

Comment: But docker file was ran in CI/CD pipeline and we cannot inspect that. Any way to print logs on console it self.

Comment: @OPTIMUS Which CI tool are you using to build the image? Is it Jenkins?

Comment: GitLab Enterprise Edition as CI tool

Answer (score 1):

For your security, you should not keep your key in your dockerfile.
[Don’t leak your Docker image’s build secrets](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/)

You can add ssh key into your CI container and mount into docker build.

Below is CI yaml file

```sh
build_docker:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    # This instructs Docker not to start over TLS.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip git bind-tools openssh-client
    - echo $DOCKERPASS | docker login --username $DOCKERUSER --password-stdin
    - mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan private-url >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
    - chmod 600 $SSH_KEY

  services:
    - docker:dind

  script:
    - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    - eval $(ssh-agent)
    - ssh-add $SSH_KEY
    - docker build -t tag_name  --ssh default=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK .
```

below is dockerfile

```sh
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git openssh-client


RUN ssh-keyscan private-url >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

COPY ingest_client.py .
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install git+ssh://private-url/project/repo.git
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

See the image https://feiyang233.club/img/vm/23.png

Answer (score 0):

You should change git url to use ssh instead of https as only ssh clone use private ssh key

`RUN pip install git+ssh://git@private-url/project/repo.git`